# Sympy works with int params, but spins with floats

Tags: floating-point, sympy

I'm using sympy 1.0 with python 2.7.10 on a mac. The problem is that if I use floats for parameters rather than ints, solve() just seems to spin forever.

Here is my script, with a, b, and c specified as int as shown. It gives the following output with or without smpifying a, b, and c:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
a = 500
b = 10
c = 333

y = a + b * (x - c) - (a * (x / c) + x * b * log(x / c))

print 'y=', y

solution = solve(y, x)
print 'solve() gives:', solution
```

This prints:

```
y= -10*x*log(x/333) + 2830*x/333 - 2830
solve() gives: [333*exp(LambertW(-283*exp(-283/333)/333) + 283/333)]
```

This is correct, as I have verified by solving numerically using nsolve() and comparing with an independently computed solution.

Now, I change the definition of a, b and c to:

```
a = 500.0
b = 10.0
c = 333.0
```

Then the output is as follows:

```
y= -10.0*x*log(0.003003003003003*x) + 8.4984984984985*x - 2830.0
```

With this, solve() spins, seemingly forever. Note that this expression appears numerically correct.

So again, the question is: how can I use floating-point parameters in sympy equations?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that solve converts floats to rationals by default, which leads to enormous powers when the log is inverted. `solve(rational=False)` should turn this off, but for me, this causes `solve` to fail with `NotImplementedError`. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11493) for it.

Comment: Also note that when the equation is given to `solve` with integer coefficients, only one root is returned, instead of two. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B-10*x*log(x%2F333)+%2B+2830*x%2F333+-+2830%3D%3D0,x%5D)  provides both roots

Comment: Yes, that's a known issue with solve. Solutions with LambertW should have an infinite number of complex solutions, one for each branch of the LambertW. You can get the other branches by setting the second argument, like `LambertW(-283*exp(-283/333)/333, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell why Sympy is having trouble, however, I suspect it has to do with the floating point representation not being exact.

One workaround would be to `solve` without explicitly specifying the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`, and then use `.subs()`

```
import sympy as sp
x, a, b, c = sp.symbols('x, a, b, c')
y = a + b * (x - c) - (a * (x / c) + x * b * sp.log(x / c))
sol = sp.solve(y, x)

# find the second root manually by considering the k=-1 branch 
# (solve provides only the k=0 branch)
sol_two_branches = [sol[0], sol[0].replace(sp.LambertW, lambda *args: sp.LambertW(*args,-1))]

print([s.subs({a:500,b:10,c:333}).n() for s in sol_two_branches])
```

> ```
> [333.000000000000, 242.528588686908]
> ```

P.S.: credit goes to @asmeuer for infroming me about the branch selection option of `LambertW`

Comment: I accidentally posted before finishing. I was going to say:

First, I see what you see, using floats.

Second, When I use ints instead of the floats, I get the solution I saw earlier involving LambertW, rather than a numerical solution. Strange.

Third, solve() returns a single expression; but there are two roots. The other is near 242.259. Should I not expect solve() to find this one, too?

Comment: Sigh. 2. When I use ints instead of floats, I see a solution involving LambertW (but it's not the same solution I saw earlier -- probably it's the special-case solution for this root only.)

Comment: @wchlm Indeed, `y` has two roots. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way for `solve` (or `solveset`) to provide both (I am not an expert though).

Comment: @wchlm I have updated the answer based on @asmeuer's suggestion on how to obtain the various branches of `LambertW`

Comment: Thanks. I see what you're doing, especially after reading the Wikipedia page on Lambert's W (having recently given away my copy of Abramowitz and Stegun, thinking I'd never need it again ;-) ).

However, your exact code as shown gives me a Python syntax error on the attempted replace():


  File "stelios.py", line 8
    sol_two_branches = [sol[0], sol[0].replace(sp.LambertW, lambda *args: sp.LambertW(*args,-1))]
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Can you help me with this? (Could this be because I am still using Python 2?)

Comment: The problem was solved by replacing '*args" by just 'args" in both occurrences in your lambda expression. 

Thanks, both @stelios and other contributors (whom stackoverflow will not permit me to name) for your help.